# Python3 concatenate 'str' (not "bytes") to 'bytes' TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, concatenation

I want to migrate an existing python 2 script to python 3 the following is working in py2 but not py3:

```
file_path = "subfolder\a_file.bin"

with file(file_path + ".cap", "wb") as f: f.write(data)
```

whats done here is just taking a file path and adding an extension with `".cap"` which is also located in that sub folder

so I modified it like this:

```
with open(os.path.abspath(file_path) + ".cap" , 'wb') as f: f.write(data)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

also tried: `with open(os.path.abspath(str(file_path)+ ".cap"))`

I also tried getting the absolute paths like this:

```
my_dictonary = {
         "subfolder\a_file.bin" :  ["A3", "B3", "2400"] ,
         "subfolder\b_file.bin" :  ["A4", "B4", "3000"] , 
}

for d in my_dictonary :
    with open(d, "rb") as r: data = r.read()

    content= ""

    for line in my_dictonary[d]:
        content= content+ str(line) + "\n"

    file_set = set()

    for filename in glob.iglob('./**/*', recursive=True):
         file_set.add(os.path.abspath(filename))

    f_slice = d.split('\\')
    f_slice = f_slice[1].split(".bin")
    file_n = ""
    for e in file_set:
        if f_slice[0] in e and ".cap" in e:
            file_n = e

with open(file_n, 'wb') as f: f.write(content + data)
```

I printed the `file_n` to make sure its the correct file path but even this is throwing the above error. how can add this extra/second file extension to `".bin"` and then open that file?

Comment: can you share the full stack trace of the error

Comment: sure here it is:```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_1.py", line 30, in <module>
    with open(file_n, 'wb') as f: f.write(data)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str```

Comment: in the subfolder are mutliple files e.g. ```a_file.bin  and a_file.bin.cap```

Comment: Can you please add the type of the `file_n` and the type of the `data` variables.

Comment: @amiram hi i didnt think the rest of the code was important but i pasted now all of it above, ```file_n``` is of type ```<class 'str'>``` as you can see and ```data``` is of type ```<class 'bytes'>```

Comment: please edit the question and add the traceback into the question body itself. Also, it is not clear what code is being executed and what traceback is being shown. Additionally, `content` is a string, and `data` are bytes, don't mix the two. It might be better for you to just read the files as strings, and skip the bytes, by using `r` instead of `rb` and `w` instead of `wb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading using the following:

```
with open(d, "rb") as r: data = r.read()
```

And trying to write using the following:

```
with open(file_n, 'wb') as f: f.write(content + data)
```

There is no problem with that **except** of this `content + data`.
You are trying to concatenate `str` object to `byte` (`content` variable declared as follow `content = ""`).

The following code will reproduce the same problem:

```
>>> byte_like_object = b'This is byte string '
>>> type(byte_like_object)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> string_like_object = 'This is some string type '
>>> type(string_like_object)
<class 'str'>

>>> string_like_object + byte_like_object

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    string_like_object + byte_like_object
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

---

In order to solve this issue you need to `encode` the `string` object to `byte` because you are writing to the file with `'wb'`.

```
>>> string_like_object.encode('utf-8') + byte_like_object
b'This is some string type This is byte string'
```

Comment: this did the trick thanks amiram. encoding the string before adding the byte data was the solution